# F# tryHead is not defined

Tags: f#

I am using Seq.tryHead but I am getting an error

```
let maybeTagDatabaseModel = Seq.tryHead tagSeq
```

error

```
error FS39: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'tryHead' is not defined
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix?  Thanks

Comment: Wrong version of `FSharp.Core`. This function was introduced in F# 4.0.

Comment: I'm using F# in Azure Functions.  My uses of Seq.tryHead work in my other Azure functions, but for some reason they are failing in just one function?

Comment: What is the data type of tagSeq? Don't guess, hover the cursor over it in Visual Studio and make the tool tell you what *it* believes.

Comment: Did you somehow shadow `Seq`? Import / open custom `Seq`?

Comment: @WarrenYoung cloning the code into Visual Studio locally and hovering over tagSeq VS is reporting it to be of type seq<TagDatabaseModel>

Comment: The problem seemed to be this dependency         "FSharp.Interop.Dynamic": "3.0.0" in the project.json file.  Would be interested in why that seems to be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors

The problem seemed to be this dependency "FSharp.Interop.Dynamic": "3.0.0" in the project.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Two of my projects were on version less than 4. Upgraded those and they work now.